# How to get Params from url for Axios GET request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Before everything, this is not duplicate.

How can i get my `Axios` parameters from URL for my GET request?

Example:

Link : http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback?Authority=000000000000000000000000000107041762&Status=OK

So parameters are `Authority` And `Status`

`Authority: How to get this parameters from url`
`Status: How to get this parameters from url`

I'm using laravel & vue.js which the codes are :

callback.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    TEXT
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "callback",
    data () {
        return {}
    },

    methods: {
        loadData(){
            axios.get("api/callback", {
                Authority: ,
                Status
            })
                .then(({ data }) => (
                    console.log(data)
                    ));
        },
    },
    created() {
        this.loadData();
    }
}
```

Controller function :

```
public function order(Request $request){

    $MerchantID = 'xxxx';
    $Authority =$request->get('Authority') ;

    $Amount = 111 ;
    if ($request->get('Status') == 'OK') {
        $client = new nusoap_client('https://localhost/ices/WebGate/wsdl', 'wsdl');
        $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

        $result = $client->call('PaymentVerification', [
            [
                'MerchantID'     => $MerchantID,
                'Authority'      => $Authority,
                'Amount'         => $Amount,
            ],
        ]);

        if ($result['Status'] == 100) {
            return 'Done';

        } else {
            return 'Error 1';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Error 2';
 }
```

Comment: If you do a dd($request->all()) what you get?

Comment: @carlos got `[]`.

Comment: You are passing empty value in your axios. `{ Authority: '000000000000000000000000000107041762',Status: 'OK' }` for example

Comment: @carlos i put code for example. my authority & status are empty for sure. and i want to get it from url. i'm using a payment getway, when payment is done they will send data base ono this url with parameters. so i'm trying to get those to send success message and add data into database. i want axios get get data from url.

Comment: With $request->get('Status') or $request->get('Authority'), you receive POST and GET method, so, from URL. Now, if you want retrieve this params from javascript, check https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Comment: @carlos well as u can see in top i used what u've said, but still returned 2 as error. which i don't get if i should pass it with axios or not. and about your link, i'm not actually expert at this and still learning, dono how if i get params, pass them into axios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this like so:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

Usage
Example URL:
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=awesome.jpg

Calling getQueryVariable("id") - would return "1".
Calling getQueryVariable("image") - would return "awesome.jpg".
```

Taken from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `{params: {}}` to pass url query to `axios.get`

```
axios.get("api/callback", {
    params: {
      Authority: ''
      Status: 'OK'
    }
  })
  .then(({
    data
  }) => (
    console.log(data)
  ));
```